# Facebook post to wall not working

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-wall

I am developing the facebook post to wall feature for my app. I am using Facebook Javascript SDK. But the thing is when i call the postToFeed() function by clicking a link, it works perfectly with an iframe. But if I want to load it some other way (ex. body onload), then the iframe shows with an error "An error occurred. Please try again later". I have provided the access_token with the FB.ui which removes the session problem, but still not make it work without clicking in a link. Below is my code:

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>
    <?php
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI";
     $token = file_get_contents($token_url);

      ?>

   <script> 
   FB.init({appId: "MY_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'stream.publish',
      display: 'iframe',
      access_token: '<?php echo $token;?>',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

My app is in sandbox mode right now. But I suppose that's not should be the problem. Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your method appears to be incorrect.  You may not be using the latest example from Facebook.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};

function callback(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response.post_id;
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }      
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Comment: Could you please close this question since you got it sorted out?

Comment: From where i can close this??

Comment: Answer it yourself.  Wait the required 12 hours, then accept your own answer.